# OO JS - loop through object array

Tags: javascript, oop

Quite new to OO Js, used to program with function after function so trying to fix that now!

I'm making a tab layout -

I create a tab by calling: tab.NewTab();
I can access the tabs at tab[0], tab[1] etc

```
var tabCount = 0;
var tabs = [];

tabs.NewTab = function (){
    var tabName = "tab" + tabCount;
    tabs[tabCount] = new Tab(tabName);
    tabCount++;
};

function Tab(tabName){
    return{
        name: tabName
    }
}
```

I wanted to make a function that counts how many tabs are open:

```
tabs.HowMany = function () {
    for (var i in tabs) {
        alert("new");
    }
};
```

This is returning the methods too (0,1, NewTab, HowMany).

Any advice?

Comment: You don't want a mix of an array and an object since it can cause confusion like this. An array is meant to only contain properties with numeric indexes. Rather, you should make a separate function instead of adding it as a property to the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `tabs.push(new Tab(tabName));`

Then ditch `tabCount`, and instead use the `length` property native to all javascript arrays: `tabs.length`

Also, your Tab constructor is wrong.  As it is currently written it should not be called with `new`.  Just call `Tab('someName')` and it will return to you the object you're looking for.  If you do that however, change it to `tab` since non-constructor functions should be lowercase.

If you're really eager to use the `new` keyword, this is what Tab should look like:

```
function Tab(tabName){
   this.name = tabName;
 }
```

**EDIT**

If you want to iterate over all members of your array, this is the simplest way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
    var currentTab = tabs[i];
```

Comment: That's great thanks Adam, one question though, as cool as getting the qty from tabs.length is, what if I need to iterate over them in a loop (to do something to them all)?

    for (var i in tabs) {
        alert(i);
    }

This still returns too many...

Comment: One upvote and the check are more than enough :)  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `var tabs = [];` to `var tabs = new Array();`.
And add items to it using `tabs.push(new Tab(tabName));`

Simple count:

```
var count = tabs.lenght
```

Enumeration of items:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    alert(tabs[i]);
}
```

Comment: var tabs = []; and var tabs = new Array(); doesn't make a difference in this example. The [] is actually preferred (since 1 argument with new Array is not that clear).

Comment: @Johan Thanks for it, I always used `new Array()` :). Will know that it's the same

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
tabs.HowMany = function () {
    for (var i in tabs) {
        if(tabs.hasOwnProperty(i)){
               if(typeof tabs[i] !== 'function'){
                     alert('new')
               }
        }
    }
};
```

but you'd better switch using it as array

```
tabs.push(new Tab(tabName))

tabs.HowMany = function () {
   return tabs.length
};
```